# Translation: I was pushed into getting past simple pleasures of life in order to catch up with the standards of maturity

Tags: traducción, vocabulario, gramática

tiene dificultades con traducción, pero no soy una inglaterra y por eso la frase en inglés puede ser mal también:

I was pushed into getting past simple pleasures of life in order to catch up with the standards of maturity.

Lo que tiene es:

Me puso a pasar por delante les placeres sencillos de mi vida para ponerme al corriente de madurez.

Gracias por ayudarme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spanish and English are both my first languages. After some thought, this is the most accurate translation I could think of:
Me vi obligado a dejar atrás los simples placeres de la vida con la finalidad de alcanzar las normas de la madurez.
Hope that works for you!